# Strings vs integers for storing data

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

What would be considered the best practise when it comes to storing datatypes to the database?

For instance, you have a support ticket feature in which a ticket can have the following statuses: `open`, `closed`, `review`.

Would you store it as a string?

```
+----+----------------+--------+
| id |     ticket     | status |
+----+----------------+--------+
|  1 | example ticket | open   |
|  2 | example ticket | closed |
+----+----------------+--------+
```

Store the value as an integer, so: `1` => `open`, `2` => `closed` and `3` => `review` or as a string.

```
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 1      |
|  2 | 2      |
+----+--------+
```

If you would save it as an integer, would you create an extra table to resolve the name of that status (lets say `support_ticket_states` table)?

```
+----+----------------+--------+
| id |     ticket     | status |
+----+----------------+--------+
|  1 | example ticket | 1      |
|  2 | example ticket | 2      |
+----+----------------+--------+
```

Or would you do that on the client side, for example:

```
if ($ticket->status == 1) {
    echo 'Open';
}
```

What would be considered the best option?

Comment: If it only has 3 distinct states, an Enum would be appropriate. Can you store Enum in a db?

Comment: You can store it as an enum. Seems like the best option indeed, can you post this as an answer so I can mark it solved? Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Typically, if you have a limited number of possible states, you should reach for an Enum. That way, if an invalid value is passed, it might be able to be caught at compile time. Raw ints/strings don't give you that ability unless you create a macro. I'd write an answer, but I haven't used PHP or mysql for a very long time.

Comment: for open and closed you 1 or 0.

Comment: @RobertRocha We are talking about multiple options, not just a boolean of closed/open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on personal preference.

- firstname: Would you store "Daniel" as string, or map every user to `firstname_id=1`? guess no...
- status: new/open, only 2 options, but here I would use a mapping.
- hourly/daily 2 options as well, but here i would take a string-type.

My preference: If there **can** be information associated with the entry - use a mapping table. If it is guaranteed to stay a "single-string", store it as string.

Picking the examples above:

- The firstname always remains a single "firstname", altering a name should not affect other users. -> String
- `status` could be extended with more information such as "general-time-to-response", "description", "team-lead" etc... -> Mapping
- hourly/daily: There is nothing more to say, it's either or. -> String

---

```
if ($ticket->status == 1) {
    echo 'Open';
}
```

this depends on how you do your localization, if any. There is no "right" and "wrong", just "working" and "not working". :-)

I would keep it as `open`, `closed` in the database, and then - when it comesdown to localization - translate that entry properly using "code", not database-queries. (Loacalization stuff can be easily cached and preloaded, no need for over-engineered queries, cause you didn't.):

```
echo getLocalizedContent($ticket->status, $user->getLanguage());
```

(Language information can be stored along with the session, so no need to pass as parameter):

```
echo getLocalizedContent($ticket->status);
```

Comment: Yeah exactly! What I'm doing now is using `enum` for storing the values `open`, `closed` and `review` and then translating the values based on the locale. Works really smooth with Laravels Eloquent Mutators, because every time I resolve the Ticket model the status property will be an object (instead of a string) containing both the actual and translated value :)

Answer (score 0):

Storing it as a string has too many disadvantages (e.g., it is an inefficient use of storage).

Your second option (storing it as an integer) is more efficient. However, do only use the additional table if you want the string representations to be editable. Otherwise, you prolong the runtime of database requests for nothing. Your example (with open/closed) seems to be a use case that can be hardcoded and is then more efficient for the runtime.

If your database accepts even smaller datatypes (e.g., tinyint, smallint), I would use the most appropriate one, not simply integer (unless you plan to add numerous additional states later).

Answer (score 0):

On a big amount of data, storing integers and indexing them would make queries faster than varchars

Answer (score -1):

I think its depends, how large your application is. If your application is large enough, you should create table for 'open', 'close', 'review', for each ticket. so that it will be easy and quick to fetch the data.

on the other hand you can handling it by if condition .